# VirtualBox guest cannot connect to USB drive, why not?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have VirtualBox installed in Windows 8.1 and I am using it to launch and use CentOS 7 within VirtualBox.  When I connect a USB drive to the computer, and right click over the icon circled in the image below, it lists the correct name of the USB drive that has been inserted.  But Then I am not able to find the USB drive within the CentOS 7 file manager.

[image]

I read  [this other posting](https://s10.postimg.org/ovsodj709/VBusb.jpg) but using its methods caused the CentOS 7 terminal to reply `group vboxusers does not exist` and `bash VBoxManage: command not found...`

**What do I need to do in order to connect to and manipulate the USB drive from within CentOS 7 running within VirtualBox installed in Windows 8.1?**

---

**EDIT:**

---

I re-installed the VirtualBox Extension Pack and rebooted the PC.  Now, when I insert the USB drive, VirtualBox is able to "claim" it, either by right clicking on the icon in the image shown above, or by clicking `Devices > USB Devices > Device Name`.  Either of these two methods now causes a check mark to be added next to Device Name in VirtualBox, while also causing a system sound, and also causing Windows Explorer to stop seeing the usb drive, so that the USB drive disappears from Windows Explorer and is marked in VirtualBox as selected.

But the problem is that the CentOS 7 installation inside VirtualBox cannot seem to see the USB drive.  The USB device itself is an [Apricorn SATA Wire 3.0](http://www.apricorn.com/sata-wire-3.html) connector to the hard drive from a dead PC that had CentOS 7 and Windows 7 installed in a dual boot fashion.  I want to access the data from the CentOS partition of the old hard drive using the CentOS 7 running inside VirtualBox on the new PC.  **Now that VirtualBox can see the USB device, how can I get CentOS 7 to see and manipulate the USB device?**

Comment: What action does your host Win take when inserting the usb drve?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your virtualbox is missing the USB extension pack. Please do download it from the respective website and add that extenstion pack to your virtualbox using the below stelps,

1. File-> Preferences ->Extensions-> Add extension.

Hope it works.

Comment: Where is the File menu?  I do not see it in either VirtualBox or in CentOS.

Comment: Please see **EDIT** to my OP showing progress.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You will get the file menu from the virtualbox. You didn't mentioned about your virtualbox so I assumed that you might be using Orcale VM Virtualbox

Comment: Does USB drive mounted on your CentOS 7?

Comment: Thank you.  I found the file menu, but what is the download link for the USB extension pack that you recommend?

Comment: It depends on your virtualbox...Can please tell me which virtualbox are you using?

Comment: The only way I have been able to mount the old CentOS 7 data from the detached hard drive is to open it in a separate VirtualMachine that is read only.  By contrast, this question is about how to access the data in an interactive form.

Comment: I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox version 4.3.28

Comment: Here you download the extension pack http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.28/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.28-100309.vbox-extpack and add it to your virtual box.

Comment: I have had that installed all this time.  I wonder why it cannot read the USB?  Here is a link to a screen shot of the extension installation which has been in place since before I first posted the above question.  Did I fail to install it correctly?  Or perhaps there is a different download required? http://s13.postimg.org/a5yfjr86v/vbox_extensions.jpg

Comment: Ok. If you have installed the extension pack then USB  is already detected in your guest OS but it is not mounted I guess. So, please go to /dev/disk/by-id/ and find your USB stick and mount it to some folder.

Answer (score 1):

When a USB storage device is connected to a CentOS system, it (and its partitions) should appear as `/dev/sd*` devices. You can use the `lsblk` or `lsscsi` commands to identify the devices, or read `/proc/partitions` to see a list of disk/partition devices and their sizes.

A desktop environment might offer to auto-mount a regular USB stick with just a single filesystem on it, but a hard drive with multiple partitions and different filesystem types might be regarded by the desktop environment as "too complex to mount automatically": you may have to use the `mount` command as root to choose the partition(s) you wish to mount and the desired mountpoint(s).